# Separation of Identity from main project in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

So I am trying to achieve true separation of the Identity from my main project.  In essence, my main project should know about Identity and Identity should not have a clue about my main project.  This allows me to build one set of dll's that I can use throughout many projects.  The way I am doing this is with Ninject injection.

So I have what I believe to be a fairly straight forward setup, let me show you:

CustomIdentityDbContext:

```
public class CustomIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<AzularisUser>, ICustomIdentityDbContext
{
    public CustomIdentityDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<AzularisUser>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
    }

    public static DbContext Create()
    {
        return new CustomIdentityDbContext();
    }
}
```

AzularisUser:

```
public class AzularisUser : IdentityUser, IAzularisUser
{
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public int EmailResendCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime EmailResendAttemptTime { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<AzularisUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        //some code to add claims, removed as its not important to my demonstration
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

SignInService:

```
public class SignInService : SignInManager<AzularisUser, string>, ISignInService
{
    private readonly UserService _userService;

    public SignInService(UserService userService, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userService, authenticationManager)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
public class UserService : UserManager<AzularisUser>, IUserService
{
    public UserService(IUserStore<AzularisUser> store, IDataProtectionProvider dataProvider)
        : base(store)
    {
        UserValidator = new UserValidator<AzularisUser>(this)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };

        PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };

        UserLockoutEnabledByDefault = true;
        DefaultAccountLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        MaxFailedAccessAttemptsBeforeLockout = 5;

        var dataProtectionProvider = dataProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<AzularisUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
    }
}
```

UserStore:

```
public class UserStore : UserStore<AzularisUser>
{
    public UserStore(IdentityDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

IdentityManager:

```
public class IdentityManager : IIdentityManager
{
    public ISignInService SignInService { get; set; }
    public IUserService UserService { get; set; }
    public IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationService { get; set; }

    public IdentityManager(ISignInService signInService, IUserService userService, IAuthenticationManager authenticationService)
    {
        SignInService = signInService;
        UserService = userService;
        AuthenticationService = authenticationService;
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private IAppBuilder _app;
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        _app = app;
        app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    }

    private IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        kernel.Bind<ICustomIdentityDbContext>().To<ITournapediaDbContext>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<ITournapediaDbContext>().To<TournapediaDbContext>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<IUserStore<AzularisUser>>().To<UserStore>();
        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISignInService>().To<SignInService>();
        kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(x => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication);
        kernel.Bind<IDataProtectionProvider>().ToMethod(x => _app.GetDataProtectionProvider());
        kernel.Bind<IIdentityManager>().To<IdentityManager>();

        return kernel;
    }
}
```

I apologize for the long code, however it was necessary to demonstrate my setup.  The problem that I am facing is that if I run this code as is, and I try to do something such as

`await SignInService.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, true);`

I will get the following error:

> The entity type AzularisUser is not part of the model for the current context.

If I update my UserStore and I set the class as follows:

```
public class UserStore : UserStore<AzularisUser>
{
    public UserStore(TournapediaDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

The code works and I have no issues. I do not fully understand why I can't just tell my `UserStore` to use `IdentityDbContext`, after all `TournapediaDbContext` extends `IdentityDbContext`. And I cannot leave it as `TournapediaDbContext` because then my identity has to reference `Tournapedia` project, which I am trying to avoid.

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: There is no easy way to do what you want. You'll have to use `CustomIdentityDbContext` and will have to get all the references across. There are ways to completely separate projects but they are not pretty and require  a lot of effort. Unfortunately Identity has this "feature".

Comment: @trailmax For the time being I have made it so that UserStore gets created by my main application.  This allows Identity to not know about the main project.  While technically, UserStore is part of identity, I feel that this is the lesser of two evils.  For future implementations, all I have to remember is to create UserStore.